# Android Studio, Deprecated methods while parsing through json files

Tags: android, json, parsing, deprecated

I'm trying to create a simple currency converter mobile application. I've followed a couple of tutorials, for example: thenewboston on youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1o15gHPw2A) and this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/. I've come to a dead end now and can't seem to find the solution. My guess is that the deprecated methods are causing the program to crash, but I'm very unfamiliar with what they are or do so i might be wrong. I'm getting pretty desperate trying to figure out what the problem is, so any help i can get will be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView httpStuff;
HttpClient client;
JSONObject json;
final static String URL = "http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=1fdb20f2772748569ede3ff56127d8c3";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvhttp);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    new Read().execute("EUR");
}
public JSONObject lastTweet() throws IOException, JSONException {
     StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);

     HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
     HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
     int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
     if (status == 200) {
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONArray timeline = new JSONArray(data);
        JSONObject last = timeline.getJSONObject(0);
       return last;
}
else {
    return null;
}}


public class Read extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            json = lastTweet();
            return json.getString(params[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        httpStuff.setText(result);
    }
}}
```

Comment: Could you please add your import statements and also your logcat response

Answer (score 2):

My best guess from your code (and assuming you have targeted SDK version as API level 22) is that you are using the deprecated `HttpClient` API's. According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) page, it is deprecated. Basically, instead of using `HttpClient`, you should use `HttpURLConnection` as explained in [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) post.

So instead of using `HttpGet` and `HttpResponse` in the `lastTweet()` method, use this:

```
 URL url = new URL(URL);
 HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 try {
   InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
   readStream(in);
 finally {
   urlConnection.disconnect();
 }
}
```

Source from the Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).